# Migrate BPMN 2.0 using Activiti

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

We are currently using JBPM in our project which has many workflow diagrams using BPMN 2.0. If we want to switch over to Activiti, shall we use the same BPMN workflow diagram, or do we need to change anything?

For migrating JBPM to Activiti, are there any challenges present?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly import the BPMN process into Activiti. This will bring in the basic flow, but you will need to reimplement service tasks, variable, forms etc.

Comment: Is there any procedure/examples to reimplement service tasks, variables, forms, etc?

Comment: The implementation of these will be specific to the source environment as the BPMN standard does not define the implementation layer.
It is highly unlikely any of this code will be reusable.